# Assigning result of chain matrix multiplication to a variable in Maxima

Tags: linear-algebra, maxima

I'm trying to assign the result of a chain matrix multiplication in Maxima to a new variable. I'm not sure as a new user why line %o6 isn't the same as the previous and fully evaluate the chain. Also why when I enter the new variable name "B" I simply have "B" returned back to me and not ([32, 32], [32, 32]). Basic questions I know but I've searched the documentation for a number of hours, and tutorials, and the syntax that I'm supposed to use here to get what I guess I was expecting as output, is still unclear to me.

[image]

Comment: When I try it with wxMaxima 18.something, wxMaxima hangs when trying to evaluate `B : A.A.A`. Watching the socket traffic between wxMaxima and Maxima (via `sudo tcpdump -i lo -vv -A 'port 4010'` on my Ubuntu system) seems to show that Maxima thinks there is a syntax error in the stuff that wxMaxima sent. My guess is that `B : A.A.A` is somehow parsed incorrectly by wxMaxima before being sent to Maxima. I find that if instead of `B : ...` i.e. with spaces around `:`, it triggers the error, but if the spaces are removed, i.e. `B:...`, it works as expected. Can you try `B:A.A.A` and report back?

Comment: @RobertDodier Ah, fantastic that works. Yes I'm on Xubuntu 19.04 as I should have mentioned. What a nuisance! I'll gladly accept this as an answer if you wish to make it such it might help someone else having the same frustration, seems to be a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't tell for sure, but it appears that the problem is that `B : A.A.A` is entered holding the shift key for at least one of the spaces, and Shift+Space is interpreted as non-breaking space instead of ordinary space. This appears to be a known bug or at least a serious misfeature in wxMaxima; see: https://github.com/wxMaxima-developers/wxmaxima/issues/1031

(I say misfeature because Shift+Space --> non-breaking space is documented in the wxMaxima documentation, but it seems like a classic example of "bad affordance"; it is all too easy to do the wrong thing without knowing it. Anyway this is just my opinion.)

I built wxMaxima from current source code and it appears that Shift+Space is now not interpreted as non-breaking space in code, so `B : A.A.A` should have the expected effect even if shift key is held while typing space. The current version is 19.07.0-DevelopmentSnapshot. I poked through the commit log a bit, but I can't figure out which commit changed the behavior of Shift+Space, so it's possible that the problem is not fixed and it is just fortuitous that I am not encountering it.

There are two workarounds, if one doesn't want to hazard an upgrade. (1) Omit spaces. (2) Be careful to only type space without shift.

Hope this is helpful in some way.